# How do i compare 2 rows from the same table (Oracle 11g)

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle11g, data-comparison

I need to create a stored procedure that processes a table looking for rows matching on a particular id with different statuses.
I know the syntax to get the row data but i have never tried comparing 2 rows from the same table before? How is it done? Would i need to use variables to store the data from each? Or some other way?

This question is a based on this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510916/how-do-i-compare-2-rows-from-the-same-table-sql-server), but on Oracle with some modifications:

First one this table may or may not have many to many, many to one,
    one to many relations with other tables.

Edit 1:

Table looks like this:

`create table Test(

    id char32 not null,

    column1 varchar2(2048),

    column2 varchar2(2048),

...

    column30 varchar2(2048)
)`

Any difference in any column will result in them being different.
Stored procedure will return only a true or false regarding if they are identical or not.

Comment: @Fioradu88 - What does your table look like?  What is the result that you're trying to retrieve?  Do you just want a list of the `ID` values that appear multiple times in the table with different statuses?  Do you want to retrieve the statuses as well?  Do you want to retrieve other columns?  What would the result set look like if a particular `ID` existed with 5 different statuses or 10 different statuses?

Comment: So, you want a stored function that takes in an `ID` and returns TRUE if there are two or more rows in the table with the same `ID` that are not identical and FALSE otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following form of select will test for dups:

```
select id ,
column1 ,
column2 ,
...
column30 ,
count(*)
from test
group by id ,
column1 ,
column2 ,
...
column30
having count(*) > 1
;
```

you can also self join the test table to itself  or use MINUS