# Compare and list differences with previous row from same table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to compare column values with previous subsequent row column values from the same table. I have seen some solutions online but couldn't find to address my need.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[compare_results_by_id] 
    @history_id int
AS
BEGIN
--declare table to insert old value and new value
declare @HistoryLog table (ColumnName varchar(100), OldValue varchar(max), NewValue varchar(max), updated_by int)

declare @previousID int

    SELECT [history_id]
          ,[first_name]
          ,[last_name]
          ,[occupation]
          ,[updated_by]
      FROM History_Table where history_id = @history_id

-- get previous row 

    SELECT @previousID  = P.PreviousID
    FROM
    (SELECT  MAX(D.history_id) PreviousID
    FROM History_Table D
    WHERE informant_history_id < @history_id) P

-- TODO Compare results
END
```

How do I loop through and compare column values from two rows? Is there any better approach? Please let me know.

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are trying to do here. Generally speaking you do not want to do looping. If you could explain what you are trying to do we can help you find a set based approach instead of this RBAR approach you are working on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i compare 2 rows from the same table (SQL Server)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510916/how-do-i-compare-2-rows-from-the-same-table-sql-server)

Comment: Yes, I need help with looping.

Comment: plz don't loop in your database

Comment: AFAIK LAG() and LEAD() are only available in SQL Server 2012+

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.history_id, max(p.history_id)
  FROM History_Table c
  LEFT JOIN History_Table p
        on p.history_id < c.history_id 
 GROUP BY c.history_id;
```

you may want to use a cte with rn

```
with cte as  
(  SELECT [history_id]
        , [first_name]
        , [last_name]
        , [occupation]
        , [updated_by]
        , row_number() over (order by [history_id] ) as rn  ) 
select c.*, n.*    
  from cte as c    
  left join cte as p 
         on c.rn = n.rn-1;
```