# SQL Server: How to replicate pandas merge?

Tags: python, sql, pandas

How can I replicate Pandas merge in SQL server?

I want to do this:

```
# merge and filter out rows that are in "both" dataframes

df1 = pd.DataFrame([
            ['A', 1, 'c', 'a'],
            ['A', 2, 'c', 'a'],
            ['B', 2, 'c', 'a'],
            ['B', 3, 'c', 'a'],
            ['C', 3, 'c', 'a'],
            ['C', 4, 'c', 'a'],
            ['D', 3, 'c', 'a']
            ],
        columns = ['ID', 'Period', 'Pivot', 'Group'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([
            ['A', 1, 'c', 'a'],
            ['A', 2, 'c', 'a'],
            ['B', 2, 'c', 'a'],
            ['B', 3, 'c', 'a'],
            ['C', 3, 'c', 'a'],
            ['C', 4, 'd', 'a'],
            ['D', 3, 'd', 'a']
            ],
        columns = ['ID', 'Period', 'Pivot', 'Group'])


out = df1.merge(df2, how='outer', left_on=['ID', 'Period', 'Pivot', 'Group'], right_on=['ID', 'Period', 'Pivot', 'Group'], indicator=True).query('_merge != "both"')
```

What I have tried to do is implement a variant of this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/511022/6534818

```
SELECT a.SelfJoinTableID
FROM   dbo.SelfJoinTable a
       INNER JOIN dbo.SelfJoinTable b
         ON a.SelfJoinTableID = b.SelfJoinTableID
       INNER JOIN dbo.SelfJoinTable c
         ON a.SelfJoinTableID = c.SelfJoinTableID
WHERE  a.Status = 'Status to filter a'
       AND b.Status = 'Status to filter b'
       AND c.Status = 'Status to filter c'
```

But it does return what I get in Pandas.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the data. But I think you are looking for an outer join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to select the rows that are in `df1` or `df2`, but not both. On SQL Server, you can use the UNION, EXCEPT, and INTERSECT operators like this:

```
(SELECT * FROM TableA
UNION
SELECT * FROM TableB)
EXCEPT
(SELECT * FROM TableA
 INTERSECT
 SELECT * FROM TableB)
```

The first three rows performs the set union of all rows in TableA and TableB. The last three rows performs the set intersection of TableA and TableB (i.e., only the rows that appear in both). Finally, the EXCEPT operator removes the latter group from the former.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql

And: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql

Comment: Thanks very helpful -- any idea how, after gathering the differences across all columns, only portray the differences found that exist in a single column from TableA and TableB?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following your question. If you only want the output to be the results of certain columns, you could change the "SELECT *" queries to "SELECT column1, column2, ..."


If you mean something like "compare on one column, but fetch the whole row", I think  you would do a join: `SELECT * FROM TableA LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB ON TableA.ColumnName = TableB.ColumnName WHERE TableB.ColumnName IS NULL`. You would still use `UNION` with `SELECT * FROM TableA ...` and `SELECT * FROM TableB ...`